# CKEditor: add a button that opens a pop-up window to a specified URL

Tags: javascript, popup, ckeditor

I need to add an "image" button to CKEditor that shows a pop-up browser window pointing to a URL I specify (always the same) and inserts a string returned from the pop-up at the cursor position. I can manage creating a plugin (I've done a couple already) but can't see how to bring up the window and accept the returned string.

This is to allow integration with a Media Library. The user should be able to navigate around the library at will to select an image, then the window will return a fully-formed  tag in a string when it closes, to place in the editor content.

I can't see anything in the docs that will allow me to add this behavior, but I may be looking in the wrong place - I'm no CKEditor expert. Any help or pointers much appreciated.

Comment: Try to look at the popup window as another input. You open popup - some url, in that popup you can pick some image, picking the image means that somewhere in the popup window context there will be stored info about the clicked image, you just need to access this info, like you access value from other simple input elements.

Comment: @xxxmatko, I appreciate the intent but all you did is describe my question in a different way rather than offer a solution. If you have any code or links that will get me closer to a solution I'd be grateful. As I said, I'm no expert.

Comment: Ask question in different way could be also a solution. never mind. Could you post some example code? You wrote that you have done some plugins already. What url you are opening?

Comment: The plugins I have written already are unrelated to this question as they only do simple layout-related tasks within the editor instance. The URL I want to open is to an internal Media Library, not a public resource, so it wouldn't help to post it here. What I was hoping for was some guidance on how to open a window from a toolbar button, collect a string when the window closes and insert that into the editor content. Thanks again for taking the time to respond.

Comment: As you say if the Media Library is internal, than it is hard to say how the content is picked within it. But you can try to look at this [plugin](http://ckeditor.com/addon/colordialog) which opens new Dialog using jquery to pick an color. The idea should be the same, it is not large plugin. I know it is not ready made solution, but maybe it can help you.